# How can i have a dynamic datatable inside a xpages dialog that updates a managed bean object?

Tags: java, xpages

I have been trying to use a datatable that I create dynamically inside a dialog. Each row has a checkbutton and an editbox. When I try to use a DOJO dialog, I can update the properties in the java object associated with it, but the same button doesn't seem to close the dialog in any way i try it.

I have also tried using a jquery dialog but I had problems with the partial updates, I couldn't fire any server side events from the dialog.

I have also tried using a repeat control but it generated other problems.

Using java beans to separate the control portion of the code from the view seemed like a very good idea when I saw some forum posts about it, but now it is creating a lot of little problems increasing development time. If anyone has other approaches other then the ones I tried, I would really appreciate it.

---

Some of the problems related to my question was due to the fact checkBox controls use strings to `true`or `false` instead of actual booleans. And that seemed to make all events not work on the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the dialog control from XPages Extension Library?

I wrote a workaround for vanilla dojo dialogs a couple of years ago. Not sure if it still works:
http://dontpanic82.blogspot.no/2010/02/xpages-making-dojo-dialogs-works-with.html

I tend to use the Extension Library for most Dojo widgets. This way I don't have to figure out why something doesn't work/I don't have to maintain the code when a new version of XPages/Dojo is released.

Comment: The dialog I was referring to in the question is the one from the Extenstion Library. Some of the information you presented though is promising, I will try to fix my problem using some of the information from you blog post.
I would rather have jQuery working with server side events but right now i can't afford the time. So thanks for the help.